# laravel add and delete column to database using controller

Tags: sql, laravel

is it possible to add and delete column to my existing database using the controller? is it possible not to use the migration? and how do my model automatically picked up the new column which is create and automatically put in inside fillable? anyone has idea on how to approach this type of situation,if you could point me into a tutorial that would be so cool.

**Reason:** i have a table with the student mark-book points breakdown **column** **example:** **[Exam, Homework,Quiz etc..]** then every term or year we will remove it or changed it or add more so that's why i need to something like dynamic approach on this matter. where anytime i can change the column or add new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way the migrations do it, use the Schema builder class. For example:

```
$newColumnType = 'string';
$newColumnName = 'my_new_column';

Schema::table('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) use ($newColumnType, $newColumnName) {
    $table->$newColumnType($newColumnName);
});
```

You probably should use `$guarded = ['id', 'foo', 'bar']` in your model instead of fillable if you're going to be adding columns.

Comment: thank you for ur answer , about the guarded how do i write it properly? should i use public function with return?

Comment: It's a property on each model class: `protected $guarded = ['col1_name', 'col2_name', col3_name', ...];` use the actual column names you don't want mass assignable.

Comment: yeah this is cool i haven't heard about this all i know is fallible but when u told me and i do search yes guarded is the reversed way of fallible this is really big help thank you  so much

Comment: by the way about the controller approach? should i use store function on this? and how bout my blade what is the value=? also the form is this post method?

Comment: You can name the controller method whatever you like, you just need a corresponding route pointing to it. As far as the view, it simply needs a `<form>` element with at least a couple input fields for column name and type. The form action points to the aforementioned route to post the data and pass it to the Schema builder.

Comment: okay thank you great help .i really appreciate this ill post the feedback here once done..

Comment: follow up question how to delete?